# Make Alt_R key act as Super_L AND keep Super_L key as Super_L

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

Alt_R is unused on my computer. I want to remap it to Super_L because the real Super_L key is broken and it does not respond. Sometimes, my friend uses my computer with his keyboard. So, I want to keep Super_L as Super_L. I have tried various solutions involving `xmodmap` but they did not work out well for me.

The solution should satisfy these requirements:

1. A key shortcut, say `Super_L + X`, `Alt_R + X` should activate the shortcut
2. Native solutions if possible (I hate installing other stuff)
3. It should not involve a custom keyboard layout or compiling any drivers

P.S. in case it matters, I am using Xubuntu 20.04.

Comment: not wishing to appear unkind, but wouldn't it be just easier to replace the keyboard since you hate installing other stuff 

Comment: Maybe. But, I am willing to install stuff (if necessary). As long as the size is not that big, it is fine (my network is very bad)